# Cloth simulation isnt working when playing simulation

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, baking, cloth-simulation

Hello i was following a t shirt tutorial and the cloth simulation was working, but then i stepped away from my computer and now it doesnt work at all. i get jagged shapes growing out of the of the mesh in weird spots.

I didn't click on anything or change anything from the tutorial it just stopped working all of a sudden. The cloth simulation wont play when trying to play the simulation.

The first picture shows what the mesh looks like before pushing play. The second picture shows what the cloth simulation does.

Blender File:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much!